# How can I create a hyperlink for the referring website using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a row on my website (MVC)

```
<td width="80%" align="left"><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Website)%></td>
```

And I want to couple a hyperlink on that row.
How can I create a hyperlink for the referring website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a normal anchor `<a>` tag

```
<td width="80%" align="left">
   <a href="<%: model.Website %>" target="_blank"><%: model.Website %></a>
</td>
```

if your `value` does not have `http` at the beginning, just manually add it, like:

```
<a href="http://<%: model.Website %>" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create display template for that if you want to be fancy or you have a lot of links on your site. See example for that: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: That is actually not a terrible idea at all. Of course, the display template will ultimately use an `<a>` tag to output the tag, but as you note, if it's being done a lot, that could be useful.